# KafkaListener Not triggered in Spring Boot test

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, testcontainers-junit5

I have a spring boot test to check if a kafka consumer listens for a message in specific topic. The kafka listener is triggered when using `@SpringBootTest`. But I just don't want to load all the classes and I only supplied the listener class like this `@SpringBootTest(classes={KafkaConsumerTest.class})`.

When only loading the consumer class, the listener has stopped to trigger. Is there something I am missing?

Here is the KafkaTestConsumer class

```
@Service
public class KafkaTestConsumer {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaTestConsumer.class);

  private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  private String payload;

  @KafkaListener(topics = {"topic"})
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
    payload = consumerRecord.toString();
    latch.countDown();
  }

  public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
    return latch;
  }

  public void resetLatch() {
    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  }

  public String getPayload() {
    return payload;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to see what is your `KafkaConsumerTest`, but perhaps you just override the whole auto-configuration with a plain `@Configuration`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration

> If you want to customize the primary configuration, you can use a nested `@TestConfiguration` class. Unlike a nested `@Configuration` class, which would be used instead of your application’s primary configuration, a nested `@TestConfiguration` class is used in addition to your application’s primary configuration.

Comment: The KafkaTestConsumer is just a simple kafka listener, No override configuration

Comment: Incase, I have updated the question description

Comment: Well, I asked about a `KafkaConsumerTest`, not `KafkaTestConsumer`. With the code `@SpringBootTest(classes={KafkaConsumerTest.class})` you override an auto-configuration and therefore nothing is going to start your consumer.

Comment: There's a bunch of infrastructure beans needed; just adding the listener class won't do anything, you need an `@Configuration` class with (at least) `@EnableKafka`.

Comment: Thanks Artem,  Adding @EnabledKafka from my Test Configuration does the trick. It turns out I disabled spring to auto configure kafka for me by just loading only my consumer class

Comment: Correct. That’s what my answer tells: as long as you provide plain `@Configuration`, Spring Boot backs off

Comment: @GaryRussell You saved a ton of time. I was Struggling to figure this, `@EnableKafka` worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was `spring.main.lazy-initialization` set to `true`, which prevented KafkaListener to start.